# Renamed Virtual Machine, now cannot start it. (Virtual Box)

Tags: 20.04, virtualization

I wanted to increase the size of the video memory of my VB, with this command:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" --vram 256
```

With Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, which is the name of my vm. The problem is, I got the following error:

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: could not find a registered machine named 'Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
```

So I renamed my VB to Ubuntu

What I have done:

```
VBoxManage list vms:
"Ubuntu" {e25093d1-9d1c-4b35-9357-429329d72921}
```

So I did:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "{e25093d1-9d1c-4b35-9357-429329d72921} --vram 256.
```

- It works, the video memory increased to 256.
  I tell myself great I'm going to go back to "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" (initial name) BUT my vb doesn't want to start anymore ... I don't understand, it's just a renaming of the vm!
- I tried to restart my vm and I have the following error:

  ```
  A critical error occurred while the virtual machine was running and the virtual machine was shut down ... Displays the VBox.log file and the VBox.png image file which you will find in the D: \ VirtualBox VMs \ Ubuntu 20.04 LTS folder \ Logs along with a description of what you were doing when the error occurred.
  ```

However I renamed it as before and I copied my Virtual Disk Image and Snapshots folder from my Ubuntu folder to put it in the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (it's dirty, I agreed), my vb is launched 2 times without problem and there nothing more wants to launch.

I checked in the `D:\VirtualBox VMs` folder and I have:

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (ok that's normal)
- Ubuntu (which contains the Virtual Disk Image necessary to start my vb, log folder, snapshots)
- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (log folder, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (virtualbox machine Definition) and vbox-prev file)

I am on an ASUS ssd 514 go with windows 10 and internal 2TB hard drive (where I put my vb)

Here is an extract of my VBox.log (in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS):

[image: vbox.log extract]

---

Thanks for your help. I run: `VBoxManage registervm Ubuntu_20.04_LTS.vbox`

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Runtime error opening 'C:\Users\majda\.VirtualBox\Ubuntu_20.04_LTS.vbox' for reading: -102 (File not found.).
VBoxManage.exe: error: F:\tinderbox\win-6.1\src\VBox\Main\src-server\MachineImpl.cpp[499] (long __cdecl Machine::initFromSettings(class VirtualBox *,const class com::Utf8Str &,const class com::Guid *))
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "OpenMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 86 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

it's weird, when I run this command `VBoxManage list vms`

```
-> " Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" {e25093d1-9d1c-4b35-9357-429329d72921}
```

It proves that the machine is registered, isn't it?

when I tried:

```
VBoxManage registervm D:\VirtualBox VMs\ Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.vbox
```

I have:

```
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 6.1.12
(C) 2005-2020 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.
Usage:

VBoxManage registervm       <filename>

Syntax error: Incorrect number of parameters
```

Comment: As I read it, your host OS is windows. How to make virtual box work on Windows is Off topic on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Askubuntu!

I'm looking at your error:

> VBoxManage.exe: error: could not find a registered machine named
> 'Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

It says, clearly that it cannot find a **registered machine**
(...)

So, Have you tried: `VBoxManage registervm your_virtual_machine.vbox`

?

### Edit:

Okay, the path is:

```
D:\VirtualBox VMs\ Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
```

You can try; (Because; If my understanding is correct about your current problem; you cannot start it? So; If you're okay with this: rename   Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to a name without spaces, so;

& add .vbox at the end of it

(**I assume?**)

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS **→** **Ubuntu_20.04_LTS.vbox**

  VBoxManage registervm D:\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu_20.04_LTS.vbox

**1 Thing I noticed:  you don't have the .vbox included in the path?**

- Could probably be the formatting (syntax error)
  or
- The .vbox extension missing, maybe?

//Best of luck

Comment: Additional comment;  It was long ago I used virtualbox; You don't need Admin privs for running it? (it was even longer ago that I used windows, but as far as I remember it instead of sudo - in windows isn't it Run as Admin or something?) May or may not be the issue here; just probably worth noting

Comment: I can not rename it manually. In Oracle VirtualBox I have an error , I can not rename Ubuntu_20.04_LTS in the directory 'D:\VirtualBox VMs\ Ubuntu 20.04 LTS \ Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.vbox '  E_FAIL (0x80004005) (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED)...So there is the .vbox included in the path ?!

Comment: I rename the vm as  'Ubuntu_20.04_LTS'
I run : `C:\Users\majda>VBoxManage registervm Ubuntu_20.04_LTS.vbox`
I have:
    VBoxManage.exe: error: Runtime error opening 'C:\Users\majda\.VirtualBox\Ubuntu_20.04_LTS.vbox' for reading: -102 (File not found.).

Comment: VBoxManage.exe: error: F:\tinderbox\win-6.1\src\VBox\Main\src-server\MachineImpl.cpp[499] (long __cdecl Machine::initFromSettings(class VirtualBox *,const class com::Utf8Str &,const class com::Guid *))
    VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine, callee IUnknown
    VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "OpenMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 86 of file VBoxManageMisc.cppthen :

Comment: `C:\Users\majda>VBoxManage list vms`

    " Ubuntu_20.04_LTS" {e25093d1-9d1c-4b35-9357-429329d72921}
    "Ubuntu 20.04" {51453d38-8b63-49cb-8ac2-1b98d5dfbe35}

The same message appear when I launch my vm , I have to check the VBox.log but I can't extract the information that I need... (I don't know how to attach a log file to my question)